# Flask app takes long time to respond by that time browser connection gets reset

Tags: python, flask

I am new to web development and I have started learning with Flask.

I have written a small app which takes form input from user and saves it in background text file, everything goes well till here.

After this I redirect user to another link, after redirection the app runs a system command  which takes almost 15-20 seconds to respond. By the time the app responds I get a connection reset on my browser. Although the background tasks completes after that.

The issue happens when the user gets redirected to below code(url). Connection gets reset before it reaches the return statement. Please let me know as how should I hold the session between browser and app until the app responds to the browser.

```
@app.route('/running', methods=['GET'])
def running():
    os.system('echo $(date +[%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S])  >> /root/Tas/logs/SN_up_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log && /root/Tas/scripts/SN_upgrade.py &>> /root/Tas/logs/SN_up_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").log')
    return 'Data processed'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not actually interested in returning the result of your system command, then I would suggest off-loading that task via a queue, for example, using Flask-Celery. You can then return immediately after submitting the task to the queue. If you want, you can send the user a unique URL where they can check the result later or inform them via e-mail.

The other option is to try and speed up your command since 20 seconds is way beyond any time users are willing to wait. You also have no influence on the user's timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well I cannot speed up the operation thats the amount of time it will take and moving further there are few operations which will take even longer. I will definitely look in Flask_Celery. I wanted to know if is it a normal behavior for a browser to reset connection if the server does not responds for specific amount of time? If yes, then can we tweak this time?

Comment: You cannot really tweak this time since it is a setting on the user side. So as I suggested, either give the user a new URL to check some time later or send them an e-mail when the task is complete.

Comment: Thank you. I run the system command in background now and redirect user to another url.